# Why my OBD2 Bluetooth adapter send double response to a PID?

Tags: response, pid, obd-ii

For instance, if the PID is 0105 the response should be 410533 or so ... but my OBD2 reading is:

410533
410533

In other adapter I put 01051 ... and the response was correct .. a single ... 410533 but this "trick" doesn´t work always.

Any idaes or comments.

Thank you.

An idea or comment or reference to understand or solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your request header (which on all "classic" OBD2 adapters is broadcast by default), you may be picking up responses from more than one ECU. To find out, let your adapter show the header (sender) ids. For ELM327-based adapters, this is configured via `ATH1` (headers on).